# How to trigger Event only after multiple network calls are all complete

Tags: android, future

I have inherited from legacy code. The issue I am facing is that there are multiple network calls occurring on a splashscreen asynchronously in Android (but could be any system per my question). After ALL the calls are finished I need to load another screen (Activity in android). Right now, what's happening is there is no way to know which call finished first and there are lots of booleans, etc. being used to track when all the jobs are finished. I need your recommendation on a pattern or tool I can use to only go to the next screen when all jobs are complete. The team doesn't have time to learn RxJava. How was this done before RxJava?

So to be clear I have right now 3 network calls initiated at the same time but asynchronously, and I want to ONLY move forward to the next window only when they are all completed. Remember, they all start at the same time but can complete at different times because they are asynchronous.

I need something like a [promise](https://promisesaplus.com/), but I think Java does not have that. Can I use a [future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) to do this? How?

UPDATE: The problem is i am in an android activity doing this asynchronous work.  Activities are user facing on the main thread.

For those who suggest countdownlatch i have a thought against it. in android the developer is not in a position to let the main thread block.  a ANR error will appear.  so lets say i make two network call threads  and then call `_latch.await();` from the main thread. now android will be waiting for the two calls to complete before proceeding. blocking on the main thread in android is not permitted for a long time.

Comment: any reason why you don't want to use a semaphore or countdownlatch ? https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

checkout CountDownLatch https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

The idea is you create an instance CountDownLatch(5); specifying a number.
then you call the await() method which will block until countDown() is called 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

if you know how many total  calls you want to initiate at the beginning, then the countDownLatch recommended by @Karlo should work.

however, if new calls can be created when other calls are already running, then try the semaphore. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

basically, you create 'n' pool of semaphore, and call acquire() when starting a call, and release() when ending a call.

just after release, check availablePermits(). if the result is 'n', that means that all calls have ended.